Why is RunContinuationsAsynchronously an invalid continuation option for TaskFactory
I tried to create a TaskFactory instance with TaskContinuationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously, so that I am sure that tasks created will have their continuations run asynchronously. However, this doesn't seem to be possible as I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException.
TaskFactory tf = new TaskFactory(TaskCreationOptions.None, 
    TaskContinuationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
//ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. (Parameter 'continuationOptions')

Now I think what I wanted to achieve is done by using TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously and not TaskContinuationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously. This aside. I couldn't find list of invalid options or why they are invalid in the docs.
So, why is TaskContinuationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously an invalid option for TaskFactory?

It wasn't as obvious as I expected.
First important thing to know is that the enum TaskCreationOptions is unofficially (not documented besides in code, hard to imagine changing) a subset of TaskContinuationOptions per this comment in the source:
/// <summary>
/// Specifies flags that control optional behavior for the creation and execution of tasks.
/// </summary>
// NOTE: These options are a subset of TaskContinuationsOptions, thus before adding a flag check it is
// not already in use.

My strong hypothesis is that to maintain this bit-compatibility the RunContinuationsAsynchronously is made part of TaskContinuationsOptions although it's really used only as TaskCreationOptions.
For example when we use Task.ContinueWith we are passing TaskContinuationsOptions that are used simultaneously for two purposes:

The subset that isTaskCreationOptions will be extracted and used in the construction of the ContinuationTaskFromTask
The rest of the options are passed to constructing ContinueWithTaskContinuation which encapsulates them together with the ContinuationTaskFromTask

This is compacted version of the source without the exception checking:
private Task ContinueWith(Action<Task> continuationAction, TaskScheduler scheduler,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken, TaskContinuationOptions continuationOptions) {

    // OP Comment: 1 converison to TaskCreationOptions    
    CreationOptionsFromContinuationOptions(continuationOptions, out TaskCreationOptions creationOptions, out InternalTaskOptions internalOptions);

    Task continuationTask = new ContinuationTaskFromTask(
        this, continuationAction, null,
        creationOptions, internalOptions
    );

    // OP Comment: 2. creating the continuation which makes use of the ContinuationOptions that are just relevant for continuation
    ContinueWithCore(continuationTask, scheduler, cancellationToken, continuationOptions);
    // OP COMMENT: this calls inside new ContinueWithTaskContinuation(continuationTask, options, scheduler);

    return continuationTask;
}

The exception that I encountered was in TaskFactory's constructor that allows for BOTH TaskCreationOptions and TaskContinuationOptions in all of its overloads, so it treats the latter argument as "pure" TaskContinuationOptions since the user can pass TaskCreationOptions separately.
For the why it doesn't "make sense" (per the comments in the code that throws the exception from the question) we need to look at how continuations are typically invoked.
Task has RunContinuations method in which the original task object determines whether to prohibit synchronous execution of its continuations. (m_stateflags includes the TaskCreationOptions bits used to create the task)
bool canInlineContinuations =
           (m_stateFlags & (int)TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously) == 0 &&
           RuntimeHelpers.TryEnsureSufficientExecutionStack();

Then calls TaskContinuation.Run
void Run(Task completedTask, bool canInlineContinuationTask)

The TaskContinuationOptions of the task continuation object become relevant here, but the role of  RunContinuationsAsynchronously is already done (as TaskCreationOptions, not TaskContinuationOptions) in helping to determine the value of the argument canInlineContinuationTask.
Also per Panagiotis Kanavos multiple comments, the value of TaskContinuationOptions.None already did officially define the asynchronous case for TaskContinuationOptions:

The continuation runs asynchronously when the antecedent task
completes, regardless of the antecedent's final Status property value

So why add a redundant option if not to maintain that TaskContinuationOptions  is unofficially a superset of TaskCreationOptions and can serve as both in method signatures such as shown above for ContinueWith?!
As a final detail asynchronous/synchronous don't mean map 1 to 1 with "on a different thread", "same thread". As Panagiotis Kanavos commented, we are at the mercy of the specific TaskScheduler (the task is associated with) in whether the continuation will be on the same thread or not (in case of single-threaded TaskScheduler implementation e.g.)
So asynchronous means - queued, synchronous - ran inline.
This is clearly visible in the names used in the ContinueWithTaskContinuation.Run method which was last described.
// Either run directly or just queue it up for execution, depending
// on whether synchronous or asynchronous execution is wanted.
if (canInlineContinuationTask && // inlining is allowed by the caller
    (options & TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously) != 0) // synchronous execution was requested by the continuation's creator
{
    InlineIfPossibleOrElseQueue(continuationTask, needsProtection: true);
} else {
    try { continuationTask.ScheduleAndStart(needsProtection: true); } catch (TaskSchedulerException) {
        // No further action is necessary -- ScheduleAndStart() already transitioned the
        // task to faulted.  But we want to make sure that no exception is thrown from here.
    }
}


Not quite. TaskFactory only creates new task objects, either as new tasks or as continuations of multiple tasks. It doesn't schedule them for execution. You can specify any flag you want, but if the scheduler is a single-threaded one, all will run on the same thread. If you check the code in TaskFactory.cs you'll see that those continuation options are only used for ContinueWhenAny and ContinueWhenAll.

@PanagiotisKanavos "It doesn't schedule them for execution" it does via StartNew.. thanks for the spam again.

The docs for ContinueWhenAll do mention some invalid options but I suspect nobody expected that someone would specify the default option without actually using the default value, None. Those methods are intended for advanced scenarios and are often not documented as extensively

It's not spam. I actually used all of these for asynchronous pipelines before 2012, before Dataflow came out. That's why I know where the code and the articles are. I could vote to close this obviously opinion-based question, or downvote this obviously wrong answer, but I suspect this is an XY problem and the real problem X is worth solving

The only way to answer your question is to look at the code, the Git blame, Github issues and maybe ask Stephen Toub himself. People asked similar things a decade ago and he answered in Why is TaskContinuationsOptions.ExecuteSynchronously opt-in?: For a relatively advanced feature, I’ve been surprised how often this question has come up recently.

The fact this constructor isn't thoroughly documented is a clear indication it's meant for advanced scenarios. Otherwise a lot of people would have asked in the last 14 years, enough to get this mentioned in the docs.

@PanagiotisKanavos you haven't really read my answer, nor have you looked at the source I linked. Main takeaway is that TaskContinuationOptions is a superset of TaskCreationOptions and that's the only reason RunContinuationsAsynchronoly is part of it (which btw was introduced in .NET Framework 4.6) 2015 or so maybe you are stuck in 2012.

it does via StartNew. wrong, and that is thoroughly documented.  Check the method, you'll see it eventually creates a Task that eventually queues itself to a scheduler

On the contrary, not only have I been looking at it since yesterday, I was following the actual calls. I'll have to say you haven't looked at those links, otherwise you'd see they are from the same files you looked at

@PanagiotisKanavos reread my last comment. Also look at this post from 2015 https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/new-task-apis-in-net-4-6/ documenting when the option was added to the enums.

So you disagree with the real Task.cs source code that calls m_taskScheduler.InternalQueueTask(this); ?

@PanagiotisKanavos so no reasoning, just statements? What is not true? I haven't really seen a relevant comment so far that discusses things I wrote - especially the fact that one is subset of the other and there is clear code of how it's converted and that it serves double purpose.

@PanagiotisKanavos how is this relevant( i.e. not spam) to my answer?

You claimed it does via StartNew.. thanks for the spam again. That's just wrong (including the definition of spam). I still think you have a different problem and assumed you can solve it with some overcomplicated code, and experienced developers could help you find a simple solution. At this point though, I think you should find out for yourself. I'm sorry I wasted my time

@PanagiotisKanavos you haven't commented on a single thing I wrote in the answer, i.e. spam. Then you made the assertion that TaskFactory just creates new objects without scheduling them which, had you read the answer, is irrelevant, i.e spam. But that is also WRONG as you can see https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs,1141: especially by this comment
// Create and schedule the task. This throws an InvalidOperationException if already shut down.

You're reposting my links. Now read 14 lines lower, at 1155 and see what the method does.

@PanagiotisKanavos you mean t.ScheduleAndStart(false); which definitely doesn't schedule...just initiates the scheduling. You are correct, TaskFactory doesn't schedule...just when it creates a task it also initiates the process of scheduling. Completely separate things.

@IvanPetrov I don't get it. At 2024-06-21 05:58:29Z you invited Panagiotis to check your answer, and at 2024-06-21 06:35:47Z you complained that he commented on your answer. What gives? If you don't want spam, don't invite it. Btw comments under your answer are not spam.

"the enum TaskCreationOptions is officially a subset of TaskContinuationOptions per this comment in the source" -- You may want to reconsider the "official" in your answer. I don't think that comments in the source code of .NET runtime constitute official statements by Microsoft.

@TheodorZoulias I invited him to compare his comments with what I found out for educational purposes mostly and for him to comment on the answer as you did.

@TheodorZoulias I'll edit the official part, thanks for the suggestion
